# Python--output file has Chinese characters

Tags: python, file-io, fwrite

My goal is to simply have +1 and -1 in my output.txt file, yet I keep getting Chinese characters

> ㄭㄫㄫㄫㄫㄭ

The code snippet below works fine in a separate Python file:

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Max\\Downloads\\output.txt', 'w', encoding='ascii')
f.write('+1')
f.write('-1')
```

Yet generates Chinese characters when I put it into another project:

```
if(algorithm==1):
     f.write('+1')
else:
     f.write('-1')
```

The code is successfully going into the if/else statements (debugged). Any idea on what's wrong?

Looked at:
[Why is python writing out in Chinese characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807660/why-is-python-writing-out-in-chinese-characters)

Comment: Without knowing what 'another project' is, it is difficult to discern why this is happening. Have you tried changing `encoding='latin-1'`?

Comment: Are you sure? https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%84%AB

Comment: :D oh, well my mistake

Comment: Strange, still getting Chinese characters ('latin-1'). I would post all my code here, thought I might scare some people off by doing that.

Comment: is there a replacement to f.write() I can use?

Comment: How did you open the file in the second code snippet? What did you write to the file before those lines of code?

Comment: I have no idea why, but putting a '\n' after the 1 worked. Printed out the +1 and -1, abet on different lines

Comment: It could mean that whatever you're using to open the file is guessing at the encoding, and guessing wrong.

Comment: Are you still using `latin-1` encoding with `\n` or otherwise?

Comment: No, just using '\n' with no default encoding. So f.write('+1\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

> encoding='cp1252'

And it printed out successfully without having to use '\n'. Caught it when PyCharm listed it on the debugger while debugging.